# Beautiful Soup won't run in command line interface

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, pip, command-line-interface

Im trying to get beautiful soup to run in the cli with python 3 so i can play around and figure out how to best use it.  I have it installed via pip.

```
pip3 list
```

shows

```
Package        Version
-------------- -------
beautifulsoup4 4.8.0
```

However when i run python3 CLI and try to import beautiful soup to play around I get an error:

```
>>> import beautifulsoup4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'beautifulsoup4'
```

I also tried to import bs4 via the CLI but that got weird:

```
>>> import bs4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/derekchapman/Google Drive/Code/Python/p4e/bs4/__init__.py", line 48
    'You are trying to run the Python 2 version of Beautiful Soup under Python 3. This will not work.'<>'You need to convert the code, either by installing it (`python setup.py install`) or by running 2to3 (`2to3 -w bs4`).'
```

I have python3 installed and running and if I import bs4 into my code it runs fine with no errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The path in your error message `/Users/derekchapman/Google Drive/Code/Python/` suggests that you have a custom folder that you have added to `PYTHONPATH`. In this folder, you have a `python2` version of `beautifulsoup` installed and when you `import`, your `python` interpreter finds this module first, as the environment variable `PYTHONPATH` is not python version specific.

You now have multiple options:

1. delete that folder from your `PYTHONPATH`, this might however break some of your `python2` code for which you have probably added it in the first place
2. Delete `beautifulsoup4` from that folder, but this would have the same caveat as the 1st method
3. Most stable and my recommendation if you want to stick with having multiple python versions: Clear the `PYTHONPATH` and delete your custom installed python versions, then use virtual environments to manage different python versions and module installations

Comment: How would I find my pythonpath and how would I delete a folder from there?  I don't see anything in my .bash_profile

Comment: check `echo $PYTHONPATH` and also your `.bashrc`, also make sure that you are not executing your script from the directory `/Users/derekchapman/Google Drive/Code/Python/p4e`

Comment: `echo $PYTHONPATH` came back empty so i went with option 3 and installed anaconda.  So far seems to work well since one of the modules will only run on python 3.6 or below.  Ananconda made it a breeze to set that up.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) you should import bs4 this way:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

Then you can initialize the soup with the following line:

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup('<html></html>', 'html.parser')
```

Note that the first parameter is the HTML document as a string.